# How to Close a window and not bring all other windows of the same app to the front in a macOS app using swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

I have a Mac app that has multiple windows with different views.

After calling  `view.window?.close()`  (which closes one of the open windows as my mac app has multiple open windows) how can I stop all of my other windows from coming to the front?

I want my other windows to stay right where they are and not move to the front.

For example, I have a layering of windows like the following (from back to front): 3 of my application windows, then 2 Finder windows overtop of those, then my front app window. When I close the front window, I want to prevent the back 3 windows from coming forward to cover the 2 Finder windows.

Please note that I am using Appkit/Cocoa.

Comment: One window should come to the front. Which window or app do you want to get focus?

Comment: I want to stop my app's other windows from coming to the front.

Comment: @Nighthawk: do you mean you have a layering of windows like the following (from back to front): your 3 application windows, 2 Finder windows overtop of those, then your front app window. When you close the front one, you want to prevent the back 3 from coming forward to cover the 2 Finder windows?

Comment: @NSGod Yes that is exactly it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by subclassing `NSWindow` and overriding `canBecomeMain` and `canBecomeKey` in the windows that you don't want to come forward.

A simple example is to create a document-based app which allows easy creation of multiple windows, one for each document. In the Document nib file, select the document window, open the Identity inspector and set the custom class to your custom `NSWindow` subclass (e.g. `MDWindow`).

My Swift is a bit rusty but the following is one naive implementation:

```
class MDWindow: NSWindow {
var mdShouldBecomeMain : Bool

override init(contentRect: NSRect, styleMask style: NSWindow.StyleMask,
              backing backingStoreType: NSWindow.BackingStoreType, defer flag: Bool) {
    mdShouldBecomeMain = true
    super.init(contentRect: contentRect, styleMask: style, backing: backingStoreType, defer: flag)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    NSLog("\(type(of: self)).\(#function)() \(self.title)")
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(mdWindowWillClose),
                        name: NSWindow.willCloseNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func mdWindowWillClose(_ notification: Notification) {
    NSLog("\(type(of: self)).\(#function)() \(self.title)")
    let window = notification.object as! NSWindow
    if (window != self) {
        mdShouldBecomeMain = false
    }
}

override var canBecomeMain : Bool {
    NSLog("\(type(of: self)).\(#function)() \(self.title)")
    return mdShouldBecomeMain
}

override var canBecomeKey : Bool {
    NSLog("\(type(of: self)).\(#function)() \(self.title)")
    return mdShouldBecomeMain
}
}
```

In the `NSWindow` subclass in `awakeFromNib`, set up to observe the closing of all windows. That way, all windows will be notified whenever one of them is closing. When the windows receive that notification, they check to see if they are the one that's closing. If they're not the one that's closing, temporarily set the `mdShouldBecomeMain` flag to `false` for use in the `canBecomeMain` and `canBecomeKey` overridden properties. When you close a window, the app automatically checks the remaining windows to see if they can become key or main. By overriding these values you can prevent the window from coming forward.

Note, however, that you will need to eventually flip that flag back to true (perhaps on a timer?), otherwise even direct clicks on the window won't bring them forward at all.